# CocoaPods - Duplicate symbols when app & framework share a dependency

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, crashlytics

I am writing an iOS app, using CocoaPods 1.6.0 as my dependency manager.  My project consists of a iOS app project (`myapp-ui`), as well as 3 iOS framework projects (`myapp-common`, `myapp-model`, and `myapp-editor`).  I'm also leveraging `Fabric.io` for crash reporting and app metrics.  My `myapp-ui` and `myapp-model` projects both make use of the `Fabric` and `Crashlytics` frameworks.  My `Pods` file looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'

project 'myapp-ui/myapp-ui.xcodeproj'
project 'myapp-common/myapp-common.xcodeproj'
project 'myapp-model/myapp-model.xcodeproj'
project 'myapp-editor/myapp-editor.xcodeproj'

target 'myapp-ui' do
  use_frameworks!

  project 'myapp-ui/myapp-ui.xcodeproj'

  # Pods for myapp-ui
  pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
  pod 'SwifterSwift'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 13.0'

  target 'myapp-uiTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'myapp-common' do
  use_frameworks!

  project 'myapp-common/myapp-common.xcodeproj'

  # Pods for myapp-common
  pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
  pod 'SwifterSwift'
  pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 13.0'

end

target 'myapp-model' do
  use_frameworks!

  project 'myapp-model/myapp-model.xcodeproj'

  # Pods for myapp-model
  pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
  pod 'SwifterSwift'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'

end

target 'myapp-editor' do
  use_frameworks!

  project 'myapp-editor/myapp-editor.xcodeproj'

  # Pods for myapp-editor

end
```

The pods install just fine, and my app builds with no issue.  However, when I run it I see a large number of errors in the console that look something like this:

```
objc[62607]: Class CLSInternalReport is implemented in both <SOME LOCATION>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp_model.framework/myapp_model (0x11252f960) and <SOME OTHER LOCATION>/myapp-ui.app/myapp-ui (0x10f2831e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[62607]: Class Crashlytics is implemented in both <SOME LOCATION>/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp_model.framework/myapp_model (0x11252f9b0) and <SOME OTHER LOCATION>/myapp-ui.app/myapp-ui (0x10f283238). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[62607]: Class CLSFileManager is implemented in both <SOME LOCATION>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp_model.framework/myapp_model (0x11252fa00) and <SOME OTHER LOCATION>/myapp-ui.app/myapp-ui (0x10f283288). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[62607]: Class CLSAlert is implemented in both <SOME LOCATION>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp_model.framework/myapp_model (0x11252fa78) and <SOME OTHER LOCATION>/myapp-ui.app/myapp-ui (0x10f283300). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Is there a way to address these warnings?  I've tried removing them from `myapp-ui` thinking that `myapp-ui` makes use of `myapp-model` (and would therefore inherit the dependency) but that didn't work.  I'm at a loss as to how to address this.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same warnings you're seeing and took me a while to find a fix. Turns out this happens when you have a dependency that comes pre-compiled, like `Fabric` and `Crashlytics`. I think it's because they are copied twice.

What I did was to add those pods only to the app target. My Podfile ended up looking somewhat like this

```
def pods
    pod 'CGMath'
    ...
end

def app
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Fabric'
end

target 'FrameworkTarget' do
    pods
end

target 'AppTarget' do
    pods
    app
end
```

Comment: If I do that then I get "No such module" compile errors on my myapp-model project, since it makes calls to Crashlytics.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that I had moved all the Crashlytics code to the AppDelegate which is outside `FrameworkTarget`. If it's not possible for you to do that you might have to live with those warnings.